# Move a running container along with the data produced by the container

Tags: docker, migration, persistence

I'd like to ask a question about how to dynamically move a running container along with the data produced by the container. I understand that the image of a docker container can be created and moved to other places, and docker volumes allow me to obtain data produced by a container on host machine. Here is my question. Assume that I have a container running that performs an iterative calculation and writes results to a docker volume after each iteration, and I want to move the container along with intermediate results (whatever is available in the docker volume) to a remote host machine that has a docker engine. After migration I will load the saved docker image and data to continue the calculation on the remote host machine. The command "docker save" allows me to get the image of the container, and the intermediate results produced by the container can be accessed from the docker volume on host machine. However, how do I know if the container is writing data when I read data from the docker volume? In other words, how to avoid concurrence of writes and reads in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A container is just a wrapper around a process.  If you replace "container" with "process" in your question, how would you address the same problem?  (For example, stop the container/process, copy the data to the other host, and then start a new container/process would be a typical approach.)

Comment: David, thanks for your reply. Containers run inside a docker engine that isolates all containers from host machine, and can only be accessed through certain ways from outside docker engine, for example through ports. A read/write lock can usually be used to prevent cocurrence of reads and writes, but writes happen inside docker engine while reads occure outside docker engin in my case. I am not sure how you can apply such a lock in this case. What you suggested (stop/copy/start) would work only if you don't stop container in middle of writing results, but there is no guarantee about that.